# Can you recommend any speed enhancements to my Excel formula? I need to apply it to over 500,000 cells, so any saving counts

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Context**

I need to take a number of activities with desired start and end dates, and check whether they are reasonable given the constraint that only 3 (for example) can be undertaken simultaneously. Since there can never be any more than 3 being undertaken, within my schedule I need to allow for activities to be delayed. While I know this can be done in MS Project, I need this to be undertaken specifically within Excel.

**Problem**

I have managed to formulate this within Excel, and it is working absolutely as intended for a small number of tasks over a small period (up to about 30,000 cells). However, I need to apply it to many more activities, over a much longer duration (potentially up to 500,000 cells in total - which currently takes about 10 minutes to do!). **Can you recommend any enhancements to my formula?** I have already done a lot of optimising myself, and investigated a few other options (see below):

**My Current Method**

[Screenshot of current method with indicative profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxwaO.png)

Please note that my method relies on the activities being given a priority number, and ordered according to this (this will simply be the earliest “start” duration).

Formula explanation for generating the profile/Gantt Chart:

1. If it is the first line ($B9 = 1) in the Gantt Chart, don't think too much as there's no other activities before you: just put 1s in each of the cells if you are within the desired dates (IF(AND(AO$3>=$C9,AO$3<=$D9),1,"")).
2. For other rows... The formula is checking whether (A) you're within the correct date range (B) whether there are already 3 activities being undertaken above you (C) whether you've already put enough 1s in this activity.

(I'm using Excel Tables where I want the formula to be consistent in every row, which is why I have the 1st and 2nd point in the same formula)

**Current Enhancement Attempts:**

1. Instead of summing the entire range, I tried setting an SUM(OFFSET(...)) so that a fewer number of cells needed to be summed. However, having tried this it just meant that formula was missing some activities and therefore led to some activities starting despite the constraint or going on for longer than the intended duration.
2. Instead of doing it a day-by-day level, I tried doing it weekly/monthly. While certainly speeding up the calculation, this level of granularity was not giving accurate results - so I need to stick with daily.

**TL:DR:**

Is there any way to further optimise =IF($B10=1,
IF(AND(AO$3>=$C10,AO$3<=$D10),1,""),
IF(AND(AO$3>=$C10,SUM(AO$4:AO9)<$D$13,SUM($F10:AN10)<$E10),1,"")). Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: First comment is to stay away from any volatile formulas in a large workbook. Volatiles functions (like OFFSET, INDIRECT, NOW etc) as well as *conditional formatting* force constant recalcutions making this very slow. So even if the OFFSET optimisation worked for you, it would have made everything slower. Do you have any other volatile functions in your workbook? Definitely SWITCH OFF CONDITIONAL FORMATTING.

Comment: Since you are handing huge data set so for the faster maneuver the first you need is select the write application, and Excel is not suitable. Think for ACCESS or SQL database, then the data cleaning.  A machine has enough RAM & Disk space enhances the performance too.  Excel doesn't have any method of formula can boost the speed of calculation, think to add Math Co-processor to the CPU !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've a huge number of cells to work with, I'd use helper columns to calculate actual start and end dates and make calculation in right side much more simple.

- Formula for actual start: `=IF(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,">="&B2)<$C$11,B2,LARGE($F$1:F1,$C$11)+1)`
- formula for actual end : `=E2+D2-1`

[image]

Now in the calendar part you can use a formula like this : `=IF(AND(X$1>=$E2,X$1<=$F2),1,"")`

### Update

How the formula works :

- `COUNTIF($F$1:F1,">="&B2)` - counts previous activities finishing after desired start
- `COUNTIF(... )<$C$11` - compares it against constraint
- `=IF(.... ,B2,...`  - keep desired start of possible
- `=IF(... ,... ,LARGE($F$1:F1,$C$11)+1)` - is need to delay, check which activity finishes earliest from those constraining your start, +1 to start the next day

Comment: Wow - this is amazing! Actually, I don't need the calendar at all - I was only using the calendar as a means to calculate the Actual Start and Actual End, as I couldn't think of an alternative method. Could you explain how the formula works? I'm not sure I understand what is going on, but it certainly seems to be turning out the correct answer!

Comment: Please see my updated post (also corrected few mistakes in original formulas)

Answer (score 1):

You would win the some CPU time by removing the isolated case of row 1, as the constant comparison isn't required of 99.9% of the rows. Simply insert one blank row just below the headers and throw away the first IF:

```
=IF(AND(AO$3>=$C10,SUM(AO$4:AO9)<$D$13,SUM($F10:AN10)<$E10),1,"")
```

Furthermore, it would seem that `AO$3<=$D10` and `SUM($F10:AN10)<$E10` is doing the same end date comparison. Might as well stick with the fast single compare without sum:

```
=IF(AND(AO$3>=$C10,SUM(AO$4:AO9)<$D$13,AO$3<=$D10,1,"")
```

Next define a named range "constraint" as a constant (refers to `=3`) for the in order to avoid a cell lookup:

```
=IF(AND(AO$3>=$C10,SUM(AO$4:AO9)<constraint,AO$3<=$D10,1,"")
```

Next opt for nested IFs instead of AND, so Excel won't need to calculate the CPU intensive "SUM" every time, when the window conditions are already FALSE. Arrange the IFs in order of highest probability to be false:

```
=IF(AO$3<=$D10,IF(AO$3>=$C10,IF(SUM(AO$4:AO9)<constraint,1,""),""),"")
```

And finally replace SUM with COUNT

```
=IF(AO$3<=$D10,IF(AO$3>=$C10,IF(COUNT(AO$4:AO9)<constraint,1,""),""),"")
```

**Cause looks also matter:**

As we already discussed, conditional formatting is out of the question. You can however use ascii characters like this "█" instead of a 1:

```
=IF(AO$3<=$D10,IF(AO$3>=$C10,IF(ROW(AO9)-ROW(AO$4)+1-COUNTBLANK(AO$4:AO9)<constraint,1,"█"),""),"")
```

But this comes at the expense of a more complicated counting of the number of previous "█"'s. For a faster alternative, use the number 4 formatted in Webdings font (looks almost like this ►):

```
=IF(AO$3<=$D10,IF(AO$3>=$C10,IF(COUNT(AO$4:AO9)<constraint,4,""),""),"")
```

Use can use any number 0-9 and change the font to get a more visual "bar chart" effect. It has to be a number though otherwise COUNT won't work and you must resort to the slower "█"-type COUNTBLANK formula.

Comment: Hi @Mobus, thanks so much for your detailed response. I have taken on board the removal of the first IF, used a named range for the constraint, used nested IFs rather than AND, and also replaced SUM with COUNT. Also, thanks for the advice on the formatting aspect (this will be useful in the future); actually, the profile itself isn't important and can actually be hidden - the dates that I can infer from it are the important part :-)

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, what is the reason that a "named range" avoids a cell lookup? My line of thinking was that by introducing a named range, excel would have to do a second operation: rather than just looking up the cell value D13 directly, would it not need to now first lookup the meaning of that named range "constraint" and then perform the formula?

Comment: Regarding your second point about removing the second sum and just having an end date comparison: unfortunately this SUM is actually doing something slightly different. The actual end date may change (if the activity has to be moved to the right), and so using the "desired end date" would inadvertently stop an activity from being properly shifted. The SUM is ensuring that enough 1s have been (or are being) included in that specific activity's row. Hope that makes sense! Thanks again for your help

Comment: @TheFriendlyAsker well as long as the name is defined as a constant no look-up or cross-referencing to a cell (and then to its value) would need to occur. My assumption is that such named constants will sit in memory all the time and reduce loading and saving times. Might be wrong on this one though...

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple simple things should see great increase in speed. The main one is re-ordering how you analyze a cell.

Excel calculates, as much as possible, left to right, chunk by encountered chunk, only deviating when the formula logic forces it to. One deviation is that if it performs a test, it goes straight to the consequential result, IF that is possible.

So if you have an `IF()` test as the first part of a long formula, and the test's result has a simple outcome, it never evaluates the other branching. `You have such a thing that would cut away almost all of the calculating you are doing.`

That is the `AO$4:AO4` test against the constraint. Fail that calculation and you have immediate output, no more processing. It just ends for that cell. So re-order your formula to test that first. That way only three rows see further calculations than this test instead of every row.

(Speaking of "first":  as `Mobus` says, stop doing the "first line" calculation in every cell. Use the range I showed above, `AO$4:AO4` (obviously different for ever column) and deal with the first row as you would any other row. Then it is never a part of the calculations in rows other than itself. The range anchors and expands just as you do now, and you simply deal with "Row 1" like any other row. Optimizing for its uniqueness does NOT help in this problem.)

Next, do the calculation of the `SUM()` or `COUNT()` for a row testing existing completion. You seem like you'd have enough rows that almost all rows would exist in a completed state, so if you test whether the date makes it of interest first, you will then have to check these anyway. Do it first and cut the dates to test down to a very few. Again, that calculation will run anyway, moving it will neither gain, nor lose, vis-a-vis it, but doing it first cuts away lots of a different calculation.

Mentioned in the other answers and/or comments for them is the idea of a Named Range. I'm all about Named Ranges, and helper columns (even helper pages) too, but your constraint existing in a cell instead of a Named Range simply doesn't matter... if you move it to a place where it won't change position all the time. Excel builds a calculation scheme and, after the first calculation, only triggers calculation for branchings of that which have something in them change. Place the constraint in an unchanging location and don't edit it... Excel will never need spend time re-calcing, etc. Put it under the data region and have it change rows every time you insert a new task and it would. Putting it somewhere that won't see that kind of continual change and it won't need to re-calc it. A Named Range is an easy, wonderful way to do that, but you can simply re-arrange that aspect of your spreadsheet if you prefer and you might if you want to change it now and then, or more, might want a user to do so. However, in this case, your formula would utterly change your spreadsheet's results if you change the constraint and there's pretty much no way you'd want that so why keep it in the sheet instead of a Named Range? And Named Ranges have other advantages, just not important to this issue. But if you do, put it somewhere its address won't keep changing (largely, "change is change" regardless of what changed) and it won't matter to the speed issue.

I have never read something directly addressing arithmetic like `SUM()` vs. string ops like `COUNT()` for speed. Looks like other have read such and that the string ops are faster. In that case, change everything using `SUM()` to use `COUNT()COUNTA()` I'd've guessed arithmetic would win, but there you go.

Yes, as you comment says, only the date for the task beginning having arrived already matters, not its hoped for completion date. So only checking that is important. This is because your problem does not include giving up on a task if it is too old. So no matter what, if it has not been completed and it is task 1, 2, or 3, it will be done without concern for its hoped for finish date.

However, the biggest change of all you can make, dwarfing all the above (including other answers) in effect is... `STOP recalculating every line over and over again.`

Once a task is completed, it will NEVER be addressed again in the logic presented. So `why keep addressing it again and again???`

Periodically (weekly or monthly suggest themselves) copy all the completed lines and paste their values. So they are done and over, forever. Perhaps you have 100 rows left with formulas instead of 15,000 you've built up to. (Doing 3 tasks at a time, you clearly can't have 2,000 tasks lined up, so I picked 100, but even 20 seems more plausible.) So those calculations wil NEVER, EVER, EVER be done again. Just think of the speed improvement there.

It beggars the mind compared to the present situation.

There would be interesting advantages to it then as well. The biggest would be that the constraint could change if capacity increased/decreased. As mentioned above, it currently would utterly destroy the past results if changed. But with transitioning to values, the old material would be unaffected. Want to change it? Copy and paste values for all rows above the change point, change it, and go forward until you change it again.

Another would be that the smaller calculation load would let you use things like dynamic addressing in a more widespread way though they'd now have a much smaller point.

By the way, with helper columns one uses for speeding things up, the idea is different than the usual "perform a difficult task in isolation" to ease a formula in another column. In this case the point would be to isolate unchanging portions of the main formula in the helper column so Excel would calculate them once and then only if they somehow changed. So in general, if you have 11 parameters in a formula, but 7 never or rarely change, revamp your formula to have their effects occur only in the helper column/s and the remaining formula read their results like a single parameter. That... can be a lot of revamping, involving a very different take on how to process the parameters, but you can usually do it and then those parts never recalculate so it all runs much faster. Sometimes you cannot though {just like sometimes `IFERROR()` siumply won't work and you must use `IF(ISERROR())} so what you can do only gains a little. But over 500,000 formulas, a little still goes a very long way.

As to the Gantt Chart aspect, I imagine that's where Conditional Formatting ("CF") raises its slowing head. (I didn't see reference to such, but one supposes a Gantt chart with 1's isn't as likely as you using CF to make nice lines. As mentioned by `Mobus`, there's better ways than to use CF. Added to what `Mobus` said, one can pick any suitable "block" character and, if necessary, simply use the "Fill" feature under Alignment|Horizontal to have it fill a cell so matching size and shape would be less important though you'd still have to adjust font to match the character to the row's height. Even `REPT()` would server.

But to make it "sing" (especially as you used the above to very much reduce the calculations involved), you could have the output presented through the `TEXT()` function and build its formatting string to include font color. That would let you specify different colors for each row's line, different from the row above and below, so colors never sit next on each other and so improving readability. Note, that part is in the cell-side formula, not in CF with all its other problems, not just its speed effects.

Shifting to Access, or similar programs, aside from not necessarily being available to you and your users, doesn't seem likely to be an incredible help as the 500,000 cells seems it would be mostly "cells to the right piling up" and not rows piling up. Having 100,000 tasks with five cells each having calculations screams for Access or something similar or perhaps dedicated to projects. But having 500 rows with three years of dates to the right (1,000-1,100 calculations per row) does NOT scream for a database program (though it still aches for dedicated software... but that simply isn't always possible, aches or no aches). Contrary to popular "knowledge", Excel is NOT some kind of "molasses in January" dog-slow calculation machine and SQL is not always some bright, shiny, 41st century wunderkind somehow existing in our world today. You're doing the above anyway so the calculation burden is being reduced to a small, small part of what it is today so...

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you so much for your detailed write up. I do apologise for my delayed response, but I want you to know you've given me a LOT of food for thought and ideas that I'll certainly take away in this and future spreadsheets. Thanks again!